# Knowing the name of an angular factory inside the factory

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to know the name of a factory object created by angular?

```
.factory('myInterceptor',['$q',

     function($q) {
        var interceptor= {
            'request': function(config) {
                //Here I want to make a console.log("myInterceptor")            
                return config || $q.when(config);
            }
        };
        return interceptor;
    }
])
```

Of course, the goal is not to hard code `console.log("myInterceptor")` but something like `console.log(this.name)` or wathever.

Something like org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNameAware in Java... is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Basic solution:

```
 var factoryName = 'myInterceptor';
 ...factory(factoryName ,['$q',

     function($q) {
        var interceptor= {
            'request': function(config) {
                console.log(factoryName)            
                return config || $q.when(config);
            }
        };
        return interceptor;
    }
])
```

Consider wrapping this in a self invoking closure in order to not pollute the global variable scope